# Is there a simpler way I can create such an array?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list of numbers that indicate the position, called `tcn`, here's part of my code (Python):

```
tcn = [2,3,5]
Li = np.zeros(10)
for i in range (len(tcn)):
    Li[tcn[i]] = 1
```

I just want to flip some elements from 0 to 1 in the array `Li`, the positions of those elements are determined by elements in `tcn`. Is there a better way I can do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's simple enough:

```
Li[tcn] = 1
```

Docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays